How to prevent Youtube from blocking videos launching from an anchor tag?
I am trying to embed Youtube links in anchor tags. However, when clicking on it, it opens a new link with an error message "www.youtube.com is blocked". I think it might have to do with Youtube since it works for other websites.
Below is a Vue SFC that I try to replicate from a Svelte example. In Svelte example, the link is not blocked.
Here is the link to the vue playground for the code below.


<template>
  <div>
    <h1>The Famous Cats of YouTube</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="({ id, name }, i) in cats" :key="id">
        <a
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
            :href="`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${id}`">
          {{ i + 1 }}: {{ name }}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
let cats = [
  { id: 'J---aiyznGQ', name: 'Keyboard Cat' },
  { id: 'z_AbfPXTKms', name: 'Maru' },
  { id: 'OUtn3pvWmpg', name: 'Henri The Existential Cat' }
];
</script>




Have you tried this outside of the Vue playground, on an actual project? It's possible that VueSFC has a CSP (Content Security Policy) that is blocking this, I'm not super familiar with Vue myself but from what I can tell it looks right syntax wise and is actually an issue with the referrer.

For me, that Vue code is working completely fine

quietWind01 has the right of it, and you can verify in the browser's devtools when investigating the network request: "document was blocked from loading in a popup opened by a sandboxed iframe", which confirms it's a problem specific to the Vue Playground environment.  See here for more information.  Running this code in a normal Vue project won't have this issue.
